# Why Full text search index is not supported in InnoDB where as its supported in MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

My MySQL script

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `informationposting`;

CREATE TABLE `informationposting` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StexId` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TargetContinent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TargetCountry` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TargetCity` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InfoType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WebsiteLink` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InfoPost` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostingDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExpiryDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NameOfOwner` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RegistrationTypeIdOfOwner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `FK_InformationUser_Id_idx` (`StexId`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `InfoPost` (`InfoPost`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `NameOfOwner` (`NameOfOwner`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `NameOfOwner_2` (`NameOfOwner`,`InfoPost`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_InformationUser_Id` FOREIGN KEY (`StexId`) REFERENCES `userdetails` (`StexId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

this script is showing the following error. 
**Error Code: 1214. The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes**

My mySql version is 5.6. When I change the Engine to MyISAM its working fine. Can any one explain why MySQL behaves like this I want to use the InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

InnoDB 5.6 does support fulltext index types. I just tested your CREATE TABLE statement on a test instance of MySQL 5.6.17, and it works fine.

I suggest that you double-check that you're running that statement on a 5.6 instance.

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
```

Also, InnoDB wants you to make your primary key column named `FTS_DOC_ID` in all capital letters. It doesn't give you an error if you name it something else, but in my experience, loading data into the table will cause runaway memory growth. But maybe that is a bug they have fixed. Anyway, look out for it.